# Is it ok to use dynamic SQL in this case?

Tags: sql

Let me start by saying I am biased; I hate dynamic SQL under all circumstances.  That being said, is this scenario considered good practice for dynamic SQL?

```
sqlDataSourceObject.SelectCommand = String.Concat(
                    "select top ", maxRows,
                    "   col1, ",
                    "   col2 as myData, ",
                    "   '' as blah, ",
                    "   col3 as Fromperson ",
                    "   'Corporate' as toPerson, ",
                    "   Convert(char(11), orderDate) as orderDate, ",
                    "   carrier, ",
                    sqlString1,
                    sqlString2,
                    sqlString3 + " AND areaCode = '" + currArea + "'"
                    );
```

This query may run once, then change the value for `sqlString1,2,3, or currArea` and run it again against a different SqlDataSource.

This code makes me angry to read.  Its hard to read, it can change with the sqlString variables, I cant run it without copy/pasting into SSMS and I have to go track down several variables to make a single change.

But, like I said I am biased so I am asking you.  Is this code, written in 2001 before LINQ, as good as a stored proc or some other technology, generally OK from a good practice perspective?

If not, how would you have improved it (remember no LINQ, this is 2001).

Comment: Looks like StackOverflow might be better for this question. It also looks like you're working around some pretty terrible database design decisions.

Comment: it is full of SQL Injection exploits for one thing

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson- Thanks for the correction.  I thought "compiled SQL" was simply sql that is compiled with the code.  Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Your hatred of dynamic SQL makes me suspect it doesn't mean what you think it means. There are tons of legitimate cases for dynamically generated SQL. Nearly all of the world's SQL is dynamic in some way, some more dynamic than others for varying definitions of the word dynamic.

Comment: You may find reading Erland Sommarskog's articles helpful.  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html  and   http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point of clarification:

*Dynamic SQL* is normally taken to mean that the *semantics* of the statement change based on some external factor.  In other words, the column names or even the base table(s) might be altered.  This was common to do for pivot queries in the old days.

It's kind of hard to tell because I don't know what's going into those awfully-named `sqlStringX` parameters, but I *think* that what I'm seeing here is really just *inline SQL* which happens to be riddled with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.  It is trivially easy to [parameterize](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).  Fix this ASAP, please.  Inline SQL is fine but there is no reason to be using raw strings instead of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures would be one idea of how to better handle these types of queries.  Granted the stored proc may just execute what the parameters pass but that would be my suggestion for one way to improve that code so that the DBA can know what indexes may be useful to help optimize the query.  SQL injection attacks as @Jarrod Roberson points out are also quite likely with this kind of code.

PS: I wrote this kind of code back in 1998 where I had ~20 possible parameters in writing a "Find Customer" routine that was one of my first assignments out of university so I do understand where this kind of code can originate.

Comment: +1 Not to mention that parameterized queries generate higher performance if called multiple times, due to the query cache utilizing the query multiple times even with different values.

Comment: @Surfer513 - if the selected columns and tables used keep changing, very little is going to get cached. These are just parameters to build a dynamic sql statement in the proc and not just part where/having criteria.

Comment: I agree with you.  I was using that theory based off of the assumption that he would be/could be possibly using that same query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a stored procedure myself.  But in any case, no matter what, use parameters.  They way you' have it there is not secure at all, and as you say, makes me angry to look at.  :-)

Here's one reference that might help (not stored procs per se, but still uses parms)
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb